# css ellipsis on fourth line with read more with css

Tags: html, css

Guys, I want ellipsis and read more tag after fourth or third line when user click on read more than more content show for this with CSS.

what I want is like this:

```
  <div class="mycontent">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also this is aweome</p> 
  </div>
```

I want to show first two few words only then after I want to read more tag where user click and pending content show. like this follow:-

```
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy... read more
```

now after click read more all content show like this:-

```
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 
  1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
  make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but 
  also this is awesome
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Where is your code? what did you try? Have you got some error's? Here nobody code for you?

Comment: am sorry @Sfili_81 just check my edit question now. thanks

Comment: There is plenty of JS plugins for this. One is: http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/

Answer (score 4):

You need to truncate text after two lines. There could be two ways to do it pure css.

1. ***Only for Chrome***

   ```
   p {
       overflow: hidden;
       display: -webkit-box;
       -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
       -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
   }
   ```
2. ***For all browsers***

   ```
     p {
         overflow: hidden;
         position: relative; 
         line-height: 1rem;
         max-height: 2rem; 
         text-align: justify;  
         margin-right: -1rem;
         padding-right: 1rem;
    }

   /* create the ... */
   p:before {
     content: '...';
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
    }

   p:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     width: 1rem;
     height: 1rem;
     margin-top: 0.2rem;
     background: white;
   }
   ```

additionally, you could use js to do it.

Comment: Hello thanks for your great answer but what can i do i make your code in codepen nothing happen ?? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vRRZqB

Comment: Add **width: 50%;** to p element. Because your view is wide in codepen so **overflow** is not happening . Hence, no **ellipses**

Answer (score 0):

my html code is like this..

```
<div class="content">
 <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
     industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever 
     since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
     scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only 
     five centuries, but also the leap into electronic </p>
</div>
```

and the web.css should be like this

```
.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-height: 18px;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    color:  8b8989;
    font-size: 13px;
```

}

-webkit-line-clamp specifies from which line the elipsis need to be applied

Comment: ashvani thanks for your answer i just want after two lines count automatically read more tag show just like this example http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/

Comment: but i didn't want from js is it possible from css

Comment: Im not using any js files, here I am just calling a class which uses css properties and i have mentioned css properties in a seperate file called web.css  even you can call it as inline css